# Sklearn datasets default data structure is pandas or numPy?

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, dataset, mnist

I'm working through an exercise in https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-machine-learning/9781492032632/ and am finding unexpected behavior on my computer when I fetch a dataset. The following code returns

```
numpy.ndarray
```

on the author's Google Collab page, but returns

```
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

on my local Jupyter notebook.  As far as I know, my environment is using the exact same versions of libraries as the author.  I can easily convert the data to a numPy array, but since I'm using this book as a guide for novices, I'd like to know what could be causing this discrepancy.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1)
mnist.keys()
type(mnist['data'])
```

The author's Google Collab is at the following link, scrolling down to the "MNIST" heading.  Thanks!
https://colab.research.google.com/github/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/03_classification.ipynb#scrollTo=LjZxzwOs2Q2P.

Comment: I get numpy.ndarray when I run your code. You sure it's the same version?

Comment: The documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_openml.html#sklearn.datasets.fetch_openml notes a change in v0.24:  "The default value of `as_frame` changed from `False` to `'auto'` in 0.24."

Answer (score 0):

Just to close off this question, the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65545949/sklearn-datasets-default-data-structure-is-pandas-or-numpy#comment115885287_65545949) by Ben Reiniger, namely to add `as_frame=False`, is correct. For example:

```
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1, as_frame=False)
```

The OP has already made this change to the Colab code in the link.

Comment: **Edit:** See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/65506605/318716.