# How to resolve problems with pandas in juypter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, mnist

I am working my way down through the chapter 3 of book hands on machine learning with scikit learn. I have imported the mnist dataset, but when I am trying to get some image it is showing me an error: [screenshot of the error and code!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/242Zt.jpg) I have import every libraries which I need to import, I have also pushed the code to my GitHub where you can see entire juypter notebook. [link to GitHub notebook](https://github.com/isauravmanitripathi/Hands-On-Machine-Learning-with-Scikit-Learn-Keras-and-TensorFlow-2nd-Edition/blob/main/chaptrer-3-%20classification.ipynb) can anyone help me with this?

the code which I wrote is:

```
some_digit = X[0]
some_digit_image = some_digit.reshape(28, 28)
plt.imshow(some_digit_image, cmap=mpl.cm.binary)
plt.axis("off")

save_fig("some_digit_plot")
plt.show()
```

the error I am getting

```html
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

c:\python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

c:\python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5048/2618338264.py in <module>
----> 1 some_digit = X[0]
      2 some_digit_image = some_digit.reshape(28, 28)
      3 plt.imshow(some_digit_image, cmap=mpl.cm.binary)
      4 plt.axis("off")
      5 

c:\python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3453             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3454                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3455             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3456             if is_integer(indexer):
   3457                 indexer = [indexer]

c:\python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65506131/why-does-using-x0-in-mnist-classifier-code-give-me-an-error) is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different way of resolving this, something that may be helpful in other machine learning projects when you work with Pandas. When slicing data, try to use `iloc` function instead. In your case, I have tried using `X.iloc[0]` with the same code and it works, no need to reinstall libraries. And because during preprocessing, as well as splitting data into test/training sets, your indices will get mixed up, therefore calling a row by its label may not be wise.

Answer (score 0):

Use `X.iloc[0]` rather than `X[0]`